# How do I bind the escape key to something else for the vim keybindings in Rstudio

Tags: vim, r, key-binding, rstudio, normal-mode

I usually use jk or kj in vim as the keybinding for escape to enter normal mode. How do I do this for the vim keybinds in Rstudio?